# Mono does not include full stacktrace while rethrowing exception

Tags: c#, mono

This behavior makes difficult to troubleshoot errors, especially in external libraries.
Example code:

```
public class ExceptionReThrow
{
    public void Test(){
        try
        {
            M1 ();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex);
        }
    }

    public void M1()
    {
        M2();
    }

    private void M2()
    {
        try{
            M3();
        }catch{
            throw;
        }
    }

    private void M3()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

For Microsoft .Net output will be:

> System.NotImplementedException: The method or operation is not implemented.
>     at TestApp.ExceptionReThrow.M3() in D:\source\TestApp\TestApp\ExceptionReThrow.cs:line 38
>     at TestApp.ExceptionReThrow.M2() in D:\source\TestApp\TestApp\ExceptionReThrow.cs:line 32
>     at TestApp.ExceptionReThrow.M1() in D:\source\TestApp\TestApp\ExceptionReThrow.cs:line 24
>     at TestApp.ExceptionReThrow.Test() in D:\source\TestApp\TestApp\ExceptionReThrow.cs:line 14

For mono (4.2.3) output will be:

> System.NotImplementedException: The method or operation is not implemented.
>     at TestApp.ExceptionReThrow.M3 () [0x00001] in D:\source\TestApp\TestApp\ExceptionReThrow.cs:38 
>     at TestApp.ExceptionReThrow.M2 () [0x00003] in D:\source\TestApp\TestApp\ExceptionReThrow.cs:30

As you can see, mono looses stack between first and second catch statements.
What is the explanation for this feature? Can I disable it?

Comment: Do you use correct symbol files (mdb, not pdb)?

Comment: Yes (I suppose, because generated mdb file is in use).
Command is:
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Mono\bin\mono"  --debug "TestApp.exe"

Answer (score 0):

I asked same question on Mono forum - it seems to be a bug:
http://mono.1490590.n4.nabble.com/Mono-does-not-include-full-stacktrace-while-rethrowing-exception-td4668037.html